# Unexpected behavior with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Object.assign() in several projects for a while and so far didn't have any unexpected experiences with the function. Today, I worked on some "auto saving" functionality and then realized that I need to "pause" (disable) the auto-saving feature for a moment to avoid double requests to the server. I went for a simple approach here to add a pause attribute to data.

So this is the solution I came up with (shortened):

```
    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            pause: false,
            form: {
                title: '',
                slug: '',
                content: ''
            }
        },
        watch: {
            form: {
                deep: true,
                handler (newForm, oldForm) {
                    if (this.pause) { 
                        return
                    }
                    this.debounceSave(newForm, oldForm)
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async save(newForm, oldForm) {
                await this.createPost()
            },
            async createPost() {
                try {
                    let response = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                        title: 'foo',
                        body: this.form.content,
                        userId: 1
                    })
                    // disable auto saving....
                    this.pause = true
                    // I know the assignment doesnt make sense, just for testing reasons
                    Object.assign(this.form, {
                        title: response.data.title,
                        content: response.data.body
                    })
                    // and enable auto saving...
                    this.pause = false
                } catch (error) {
                    //
                }
            },
        },
        created() {
            this.debounceSave = _.debounce((n, o) => this.save(n,o), 300)
        },
        async mounted() {
            //
        }
    })
```

I noticed tough that if I use Object.assign then the auto saving feature is not disabled and pause remains "false", hence not deactivating the auto saving feature (bad...).

I played around it and could solve the problem by using a promise:

```
                async createPost() {
                try {
                    let response = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                        title: 'foo',
                        body: this.form.content,
                        userId: 1
                    })
                    // disable auto saving....
                    this.pause = true
                    // I know the assignment doesnt make sense, just for testing reasons
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        Object.assign(this.form, {
                            title: response.data.title,
                            content: response.data.body
                        })
                        resolve()
                    })
                    .then(() => this.pause = false)
                    // and enable auto saving...
                    //this.pause = false
                } catch (error) {
                    //
                }
            },
        },
```

When using a promise I had to make sure to uncomment

```
// this pause = false
```

Which just increased my confusing as this shouldn't have any effect (I might be wrong...).

So the question now is: What is going on? Why does the initial approach not work? Why do I have to wrap it inside a Promise to make it ? Is it because of the "shallow copy" nature of Object assign? And if yes, can somebody maybe explain it?

**Here's a snippet**:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pause: false,
    form: {
      title: '',
      slug: '',
      content: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    form: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newForm, oldForm) {
        if (this.pause) {
          return
        }
        this.debounceSave(newForm, oldForm)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async save(newForm, oldForm) {
      await this.createPost()
    },
    async createPost() {
      try {
        let response = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
          title: this.form.title,
          body: this.form.content,
          userId: 1
        })
        this.pause = true
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Object.assign(this.form, {
              title: response.data.title,
              content: response.data.body
            })
            resolve()
          })
          .then(() => this.pause = false)
        //this.pause = false
      } catch (error) {
        //
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.debounceSave = _.debounce((n, o) => this.save(n, o), 300)
  },
  async mounted() {
    //
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ pause }}</h1>
  Title <input type="text" v-model="form.title"><br> Content <input type="text" v-model="form.content">
  <p>{{ form }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `Object.assign()` is a shallow copy. A truly general deep copy is a surprisingly hard problem.

Comment: I doubt that `Object.assign` and `_.assign` create different behaviors. Could you [create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) or a fiddle?

Comment: You are right, the only solution that finally worked was using a promise. I adjusted my question accordingly.

Comment: I didn't understand the `pause` and the autosave part. I'm speculating here: Vue probably adds getters and setters to properties inside `data`. So, the order of `this.form` update and `watch` calls might be different than what you are expecting. Please add a debugger and verify it.

Comment: added the code snippet. Unfortunately you cannot see the requestes here, but you can basically just run it in your browser by creating a html file. If i dont wrap Object.assign into a promise then assigning any values to "this.pause" doesnt work at all.

Comment: Why are you wrapping a synchronous operation with a promise? As for implementing actual pausing: buffer your data. Have a current state object, and have an additional "to save" state object, and only update "current" as the last step when you send the "to save" data to the server and it's been accepted. Pausing then becomes a matter of having `if (paused) return` at the top of the function that tries to get the "to save" data sent to the server.

Comment: Hi Mike, any chance for a fiddle? Frankly, it is my first time working with auto saving and indeed gives me a hard time.

Comment: This is the reason why I never get to like vue, I simply hate “magic”.

Comment: I ve been struggling with this apparently the whole day and cried a few times...but both, Mikes and your comments helped me. I also accepted your answer btw. Thank you to you both.

Comment: but can you explain please why you are putting the saved data back to the user input? just want to understand the use case, since the accepted answer is not really correct

Comment: the server returns a timestamp that is then assigned to the final form (it is split into published_time and published_date). this then definitely triggers the "watch" event.

Comment: but why do you actually think his answer is not correct? I tested what he wrote myself by setting sync to true and it then works (as) expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has nothing to do with `Object.assign`. You need to understand how Vue’s watcher does its job under the hood.

Long story short, the `handler` callback, by default, is not synchronously called, it’s scheduled asynchronously till before next render or next tick.

When you synchronously set `pause=true`, trigger the watcher, then set `pause=false`, by the time the async handler is called, `pause` is already set back to `false`. This also explains why the promise version works, cus promise is async too.

If you want handler to be a sync call, you need to also set the `flush: "sync"` watch option in v3, in v2 I guess it’s `sync: true` (pls double check yourself).

Comment: Thank You, that makes sense.

Comment: I finally decided not to use watch any more and will use an input change event on the form (there for instance it is easy to do this.pause, and it even behaves as expected), but thank you again for helping me out, very much appreciated.